# How do I search for email on the server in Windows Mail?

Tags: windows-8, windows-rt, microsoft-surface, windows-mail

The Windows 8 mail app only downloads up to 2 weeks of mail down to my Surface. My Windows Phone does the same, but if I search my email and there's nothing within the last 2 weeks, the phone prompts me to search the server for more mail-- I get a prompt that says something like "Search more in gmail".

Searching in Windows Mail on my Surface, however does not give me the same kind of prompt. Is this feature not supported in the Windows Mail app?

If it makes a difference, I'm using gmail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your email account setting, in `Accounts`, select your GMail account, then in `Download Email From`, select `Anytime`. That will slowly download/sync everything from the server.

Comment: not exactly what I was looking for, but I guess storing everything locally isn't as big of a deal for a tablet.

Comment: So far I don't see any GMail App (for Win8 or RT, neither from Google or 3rd party). And the standard Mail App don't seem to support imap server side search. And don't even start me on the folder level ...

Comment: [As of now](http://www.v3.co.uk/v3-uk/news/2231503/google-shuns-windows-8-for-app-development) Google's not interested in their competitor's desktop/mobile OS.